# Not able to access HDFS

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I installed cloudera vm and started trying some basic stuff. First I just wanted to ls the hdfs directoires. so I issued the below command.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /
ls: Failed on local exception: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable; Host Details : local host is: "quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15"; destination host is: "quickstart.cloudera":8020;
```

though ps -fu hdfs says both namenode and data node is running. I checked the status using the service command.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode status
Hadoop namenode is not running [FAILED]
```

Thinking all the problems will be resolved if I restart all the services, I executed the below command.

```
[cloudera@quickstart conf]$ sudo /home/cloudera/cloudera-manager --express --force
[QuickStart] Shutting down CDH services via init scripts...
[QuickStart] Disabling CDH services on boot...
[QuickStart] Starting Cloudera Manager daemons...
[QuickStart] Waiting for Cloudera Manager API...
[QuickStart] Configuring deployment...
Submitted jobs: 92
[QuickStart] Deploying client configuration...
Submitted jobs: 93
[QuickStart] Starting Cloudera Management Service...
Submitted jobs: 101
[QuickStart] Enabling Cloudera Manager daemons on boot...
```

Now I thought all services will be up so again checked the status of namenode service. Again it came failed.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode status
Hadoop namenode is not running [FAILED]
```

Now I decided to manually stop and start the namenode service. Again not much use.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode stop
no namenode to stop
Stopped Hadoop namenode: [ OK ]
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode status
Hadoop namenode is not running [FAILED]
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start
starting namenode, logging to /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-quickstart.cloudera.out
Failed to start Hadoop namenode. Return value: 1 [FAILED]
```

I checked the file /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-quickstart.cloudera.out . It just said below

```
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.RFA
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "RFA".
```

I also checked /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-cmf-hdfs-NAMENODE-quickstart.cloudera.log.out . Found below when I searched for error. Can anyone please suggest me what is the best way to get the services back on track. Unfortunately I am not able to access cloudera manager from browser. Anything that I can do from command line?

```
2016-02-24 21:02:48,105 WARN com.cloudera.cmf.event.publish.EventStorePublisherWithRetry: Failed to publish event: SimpleEvent{attributes={ROLE_TYPE=[NAMENODE], CATEGORY=[LOG_MESSAGE], ROLE=[hdfs-NAMENODE], SEVERITY=[IMPORTANT], SERVICE=[hdfs], HOST_IDS=[quickstart.cloudera], SERVICE_TYPE=[HDFS], LOG_LEVEL=[WARN], HOSTS=[quickstart.cloudera], EVENTCODE=[EV_LOG_EVENT]}, content=Only one image storage directory (dfs.namenode.name.dir) configured. Beware of data loss due to lack of redundant storage directories!, timestamp=1456295437905} - 1 of 17 failure(s) in last 79302s
java.io.IOException: Error connecting to quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15:7184
at com.cloudera.cmf.event.shaded.org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver.getChannel(NettyTransceiver.java:249)
at com.cloudera.cmf.event.shaded.org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver.<init>(NettyTransceiver.java:198)
at com.cloudera.cmf.event.shaded.org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver.<init>(NettyTransceiver.java:133)
at com.cloudera.cmf.event.publish.AvroEventStorePublishProxy.checkSpecificRequestor(AvroEventStorePublishProxy.java:122)
at com.cloudera.cmf.event.publish.AvroEventStorePublishProxy.publishEvent(AvroEventStorePublishProxy.java:196)
at com.cloudera.cmf.event.publish.EventStorePublisherWithRetry$PublishEventTask.run(EventStorePublisherWithRetry.java:242)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

check witch process is using the port 7184 of namenode (i.e netstat linux command)
and kill that and then restart

Or

change you namenode port from conf and restart hadoop